# Access a VB script object from executed C# application

Tags: c#, vbscript

A VBScript are loaded within another application, the application thats loading/executing the VBScript are creating an object so it's possible to get and set variables to and from the application loading the VBScript.

In the loaded VBScript I'm reading a variable with the following command:

```
ApplicationName.GetStringVariable("string1")
```

I'm executing my C# application from the VBScript with the following commnand:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = WshShell.Run("c:\TestAppDelete.exe", 1, true)
```

I use the bWaitOnReturn so that the VBScript are running while my other C# application are running. But I can't find a way to access this VBScript object from my C# application. It tells me the object are not existing. This is my C# code:

I'm executing an exe from a VBScript with the following code trying to access the VBScript object:

```
MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass();
sc.Language = "VBScript";
sc.AddCode("MsgBox ApplicationName.GetStringVariable(\"string1\")");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `TestAppDelete.exe` you create a fresh new process.  When you create a `ScriptControlClass` you create a fresh new scripting context in your fresh new process.  When you add code to that script that uses `ApplicationName` that object doesn't exist and therefore fails.

Instead of creating a C# .exe consider creating a COM compatible C# .dll instead.

Comment: Any way to find that specific process and access the object directly?